# Running hadoop jobs on Amazon ec2: multi node cluster

Tags: amazon-ec2, hadoop, mapreduce

I have to run hadoop mapreduce jobs on Amazon EC2 cluster.

I tried the setup using existing AMI's. But after starting master and clients "jps" doesn't list any nodes.

SO even after using the public hadoop AMI do we have to do the hadoop setup for masters and slaves? How will master know the IP address of slaves??

Can anyone please direct me to some good documents.
I am banging my head on this for more than 12 hrs now.

Can anyone please help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative to what Matthew suggested, is the use of Whirr.

Whirr makes it really easy to deploy a Hadoop cluster on Amazon, and you don't have to pay for the mapreduce instaces. And you can control the version of the cluster.

Here's the project homepage:
http://whirr.apache.org/

Here is the quickstart guide for installing Hadoop. It takes like 5 minutes for a running Hadoop cluster.
http://whirr.apache.org/docs/0.6.0/quick-start-guide.html

Comment: Good linkage. Whirr has turned into a viable alternative in the last 12 months.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Amazon's Elastic MapReduce framework instead. You can dynamically spin up and down machines & clusters alike and you don't have to worry about configuring them to talk to each other.

http://aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/

It's used by lots of people, and it's mostly reliable. It will save you an absolute TON of work normally spent setting up and administering a cluster. Just one thing is different to regular hadoop - it's best to put things in S3 instead of HDFS (as the clusters are transient, so the HDFS data disappears with the cluster).

Comment: Great answer. Should note that elastic MR is slightly more expensive than setting it up your self on a ec2 cluster, which may add up if the cluster is large enough.

Comment: That's only true if you don't utilize spot-instances. Pro tip: make 1/2 of your nodes spot-priced TASK nodes and you'll save a lot of money.

Comment: ahhh i never knew that..thanks Matthew.  You saved me some coin!

Comment: No problem :-). It's a pretty new feature.